# Errors Faced in Patching PATCH_SUPEE-6285

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I am facing errors while patching `PATCH_SUPEE-6285`. I've checked and confirm on the correct version, Security patch 5994 has been successfully installed.
What is the issue facing here?

> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>   ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
>
> patching file app/Mage.php
>   patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
>   Hunk #1 succeeded at 89 with fuzz 2 (offset -6 lines).
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
>   patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
>   patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
>   Hunk #1 succeeded at 31 with fuzz 1.
>   patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
>   patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
>   patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
>   patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
>   patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
>   Hunk #1 FAILED at 115.
>   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml.rej
>   patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
>   patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
>   patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
>   patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
>   patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
>   patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
>   patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
>   patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
>   patching file errors/processor.php
>   Hunk #1 FAILED at 460.
>   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file errors/processor.php.rej

Comment: please confirm that rwd theme is exist and failed .phtml files exist in respective location?

Comment: Hi. Appreciate your reply.
I confirm that the following is in place.
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml and errors/processor.php

Answer (score 0):

Replace that file with one from a fresh Magento installation and then try to patch again.